# JPA, Hibernate, Map of Collections using @MapKeyColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to have a map of collections? With the code below the User has some purchases, but I want to map it so the Product entity (or product id) is the key, and the values are all the purchases of a type Product.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Purchase.class, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Map<Long, List<Purchase<Product>>> purchases = new HashMap<>();

}

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

}

@Entity
public class Purchase<T extends Product> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Prodect.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private T product;

    @Column(name = "purchase_date")
    private Date purchaseDate;

}
```

Exception;

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of test.domain.Purchase.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of test.domain.Purchase.id
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of test.domain.Purchase.id
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field test.domain.Purchase.id to java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

Specs in JSR317v2.0 only consider Map Collections of

1. Basic type
2. Embeddable type
3. Entities.

In the key and value part of the map, it seems

```
private Map<Long, List<Purchase<Product>>> purchases = new HashMap<>();
```

It is more complex for the purpose of the specs.

Consider have something like this for your requirement.

> but I want to map it so the Product entity (or product id) is the key,
>   and the values are all the purchases of a type Product.

```
private Map<Product, Purchase> purchases
```

and use @MapKey

> The MapKey annotation is used to specify the special case where the
>   map key is itself the primary key or a persistent field or property of
>   the entity that is the value of the map. The MapKeyClass annotation is
>   not used when MapKey is specified.

Note:     **@MapKeyColumn(name = "product_id")** only gives the column name does nothing with the desired configuration just give the column name in the table,